# Как из словаря удалить элемент внутри другого словаря?

Tags: python, алгоритм, циклы, dict, удаление

Вот мой код:

```
shop = {'мучное': {'хлеб': 200},'молочные': {'сыр': 200}}

for section in shop.values():
    print(section)
    print(type(section))
    section.pop('хлеб')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\python\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    section.pop('хлеб')
KeyError: 'хлеб'
```

Вот сама ошибка. Допустим надо удалить "сыр" из раздела молочные. Сыр удаляется, но сам раздел остаётся. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [dict.pop](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/pop)

> If key is not found and default argument is not specified - KeyError exception is raised

Замените `section.pop('хлеб')` на `section.pop('хлеб', None)`.

Потом можно пройтись по всем разделам еще раз и удалить пустые.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
shop = {'мучное': {'хлеб': 200},'молочные': {'сыр': 200}}
del_list = ['сыр']

for sk, section in list(shop.items()):
    print(section)
    print(type(section))
    for k in set(section.keys()):
        if k in del_list:
            del section[k]
            print('удалён товар', k)
    if not section:
        del shop[sk]
        print('удалён раздел', sk)
```

Вывод:

```
{'хлеб': 200}
<class 'dict'>
{'сыр': 200}
<class 'dict'>
удалён товар сыр
удалён раздел молочные
```

Содержимое `shop` после выполнения кода:

```
{'мучное': {'хлеб': 200}}
```

Comment: `set(section.keys())` разве ключи в словаре повторяются? Зачем это преобразование?
И думаю, оптимальнее было бы делать цикл по `del_list` и проверять наличие этого элемента в словаре перед удалением

Comment: @asanisimov Ну, можно было `list` сделать. Но что-то делать надо, иначе будет ошибка изменения словаря при итерации по нему. Насчёт оптимальнее варианта да, тут вы правы. Но тут не было задачи найти идеальное решение, автор вопроса не знает, как в принципе это сделать, я сходу предложил вариант.